# How to find next or previous number of any number in np.float64?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, floating-point

Can I say these?

- `(1 - np.finfo(np.float64).epsneg)*x` is the number right before `x` for any `x` in `float64`.
- `(1 + np.finfo(np.float64).eps)*x` is the number right after `x` for any `x` in `float64`.

If so why?

Or is there a better or right way to find the number right next/previous to any number in float64?

---

I wanted to find the closest number to `4.3` which is smaller than `4.3`. So tried `4.3 - np.finfo(float).epsneg` like below.

```py
print(repr(np.float64(4.3)))
print(repr(np.float64(4.3 - np.finfo(float).epsneg)))
```

The result was like this.

```
4.2999999999999998
4.2999999999999998
```

So, I came up with a candidate solution `(1 - np.finfo(float).epsneg)*4.3` and tried it.

```py
print(repr((1 - np.finfo(float).epsneg)*4.3))
print(" -5", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999984)))
print(" -4", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999985)))
print(" -3", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999986)))
print(" -2", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999987)))
print(" -1", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999988)))
print("  *", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999989)))
print(" +1", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999990)))
print(" +2", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999991)))
print(" +3", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999992)))
print(" +4", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999993)))
print(" +5", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999994)))
print(" +6", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999995)))
print(" +7", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999996)))
print(" +8", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999997)))
print(" +9", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999998)))
print("+10", repr(np.float64(4.2999999999999999)))
print("  #", repr(np.float64(4.3)))
```

The result was like below.

```
4.2999999999999989
 -5 4.299999999999998
 -4 4.2999999999999989
 -3 4.2999999999999989
 -2 4.2999999999999989
 -1 4.2999999999999989
  * 4.2999999999999989
 +1 4.2999999999999989
 +2 4.2999999999999989
 +3 4.2999999999999989
 +4 4.2999999999999989
 +5 4.2999999999999998
 +6 4.2999999999999998
 +7 4.2999999999999998
 +8 4.2999999999999998
 +9 4.2999999999999998
+10 4.2999999999999998
  # 4.2999999999999998
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that you want is called [`nextafter`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/generated/numpy.nextafter.html).  For example, to find the floating point number closest to 4.3 that is below 4.3:

```
In [4]: np.nextafter(4.3, 0)                                                                                     
Out[4]: 4.299999999999999
```

The difference between those values is about 8.88e-16:

```
In [5]: 4.3 - np.nextafter(4.3, 0)                                                                               
Out[5]: 8.881784197001252e-16
```

The second argument specifies the direction that is considered "after".  A value less than the first argument means look to smaller values, and a value larger means look towards bigger values; `-np.inf` and `np.inf` can be used.  For example, the first floating point number larger than 4.3 is

```
In [6]: np.nextafter(4.3, np.inf)                                                                                
Out[6]: 4.300000000000001
```